# HttpResponseMessage is IsSuccessStatusCode C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

I have the API in which I am trying to use PutAsync to update some fields. If the Put is successful I have message that will be sent as Response. But if the there are any exception when doing that I will have to send the exception message as response

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = (await client_Name.PutAsync(c_URL, httpContent));

if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return Ok(serviceResponse);
}
else
{
    string errormessage = responseMessage.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

I am not sure how to handle the HttpResponseMessage exception. I understand `responseMessage.StatusCode` gives the status but alos not sure how to construct them as response as the return type is `Task<IHttpActionResult>`

Comment: You could always return a `BadRequest(errorMessage)` which will return a valid status as well as the message. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.badrequest(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: [Exception handling in Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27137701/296861)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of message you would like to send back. Most likely it seems that just 500 is OK. Then you can just return InternalServerError:

```
return InternalServerError(new Exception(...));
```

If you want to differentiate among various statuses like 500, 403, etc. you can do that as well. You can use

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse()
```

to send anything back with code, message, etc.

If you just want to server as a kind of proxy and return the code directly, then you can use this:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode)
```

All in all these are various options to achieve the same result, i.e. to return an http status code with some message back. It's up to you to decide exactly what do you want.

Comment: If I am using `return Request.CreateErrorResponse()` will I be doing like `return Request.CreateErrorResponse(responseMessage.StatusCode)` ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You need to add message that you can either send empty string or get the message from the response. It depends on your response if you have the status text or perhaps it is in content. You need to check.

Comment: P.S. You can use `ReasonPhrase` and `Content` properties of responseMessage to see what values are in there and decide what you will send further.

Comment: @Sid Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to return :

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Any object");
```

Here in object field you can send your error.