# ASP.NET exceptions not going through Application_Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement global error handling in an ASP.NET Web API 2 app. To kick things off, I have a controller and I simply `throw new Exception("ouch");` from there. I've added an error handler in `Application_Error` in my `Global.asax.cs`, which gets the last error, produces an error response message and closes the response. In addition, the following are set in `Web.config`:

- `<customErrors mode="Off" />`
- `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />`
- I'm running it locally on IIS Express 10, in Integrated pipeline mode
- I've replaced the default `IExceptionHandler` service with one that simply lets exceptions pass through to the application level

When I throw my error, I would expect my custom error response to show up. However, I get the standard IIS error page instead, which refers to my previously thrown and uncaught `ouch` exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.

In addition:

- `Application_Error` is not triggered
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` is not triggered
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` is not triggered

Why is this? What have I missed? Where are these exceptions ending up and how can I handle them?

Comment: There are few ways to handle exception in Web API. [Exception handling in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137431/exception-handling-in-web-api/27137701#27137701) is another way.